# Trim Error occuring in PHP

Tags: php, html

I am designing an application and in my modal came across a strange error

```
<b>Warning</b>:  trim() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\gurukul\demo2\controller\routemgmt\route_mgmt.php</b> on line <b>7</b><br />
61
```

As far as I can understand its passing an array instead of string in trim. Below is the modal where its showing the error lies :

```
<?php
include_once dirname(dirname(dirname(__FILE__))) . "/const.php";
include_once PHP_PATH . "/config1.php";
include_once CONFIG_PATH.'/modal/routemgmt/route_mgmt.php';

function sanitize($input) {
    return htmlspecialchars(trim($input));
}

// Sanitize all the incoming data
$sanitized = array_map('sanitize', $_POST);
$reason = $sanitized['reason'];

if($reason == "insert"){
    $staffs = [];
    $stops = [];
    $name = $sanitized['rname'];
    $code = $sanitized['rcode'];
    $desc = $sanitized['rdesc'];
    $vnum = $sanitized['vnum'];
    $stf = $_POST['staff'];
    $st = isset($_POST['stops'])? $_POST['stops']: [];
    $st = [];
//    foreach($staffs as $staff){
//        $stf[] = array_map('sanitize', $staff);
//    }
//    if(isset($stops)){
//        foreach($stops as $stop){
//            $st[] = array_map('sanitize', $stop);
//        }
//    }

    $val = insertRoute($conn,$name, $code, $desc, $vnum, $stf, $stops);
    echo $val;
}

if($reason == "view"){
    $id = $sanitized['id'];
    $val = [];

    $val = viewRoute($conn,$id);
    echo json_encode($val);
}

if($reason == "edit"){
    $stf = [];
    $stp = [];
    $id = $sanitized['pkid'];
    $name = $sanitized['rname'];
    $code = $sanitized['rcode'];
    $desc = $sanitized['rdesc'];
    $vnum = $sanitized['vnum'];
    $estaffs = $_POST['estaff'];
    $estops = $_POST['estops'];
    $edel = $_POST['del'];

    foreach($estaffs as $val){
        $stf[] = array_map('sanitize', $val);
    }
    foreach($estops as $val){
        $stp[] = array_map('sanitize', $val);
    }
    $cnt = 0;$n_stp = [];
    for($i = 0; $i<sizeof($stp); $i++){
        if($stp[$i]['stat'] != "Exist"){
            $n_stp[$cnt] = $stp[$i];
            $cnt++;
        }
    }

    $val = editValues($conn,$id, $name, $code, $desc, $vnum, $stf, $n_stp, $edel);
    echo $val;
}

if($reason == "delRoute"){
    $id = $sanitized['id'];
    $val = delRoute($conn,$id);
    echo $val;
}
```

Can someone please guide me how can I resolve this ? Tried few debugging steps but didnt get succeded

Comment: What is the structure of ```$estaffs = $_POST['estaff'];``` ? I think it may be multidimensional array.

Comment: I guess you have an array in your `$_POST`, `<input name="something[]">`, or similar.

Comment: As an aside: You are using `htmlspecialchars()` all wrong.  It is designed to be used to safely **output** content to be included in HTML, never designed to be used on **input**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could rewrite your sanitize function as:

```
function sanitize($input) {
    if (is_array($input))
         return array_map('sanitize', $input);
    else
        return htmlspecialchars(trim($input));
}
```

That way it will handle a value passed to it which is an array.

Comment: I am able to add the item but is unable to edit the same

Comment: I'm sorry I don't know what you mean by that. Can you update the question?

Comment: I mean to say if I change the function as per your advise the error disappears but I am unable to edit the entry as Save button becomes disable

Comment: Hi Jigna, i don't know what Save button you are talking about. Perhaps you need to ask a new question. In the meantime though, if this solved your question it would be good if you could mark it accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Your `$_POST` variable probably contains some kind of array. Either figure out what you're posting by checking the output of `var_dump($input)` inside your `sanitize` function or change it to this:

```
function sanitize($input) {
    return htmlspecialchars(trim((string) $input));
}
```

if you just want it to work.

Comment: Probably the error will be then _"Array to string conversion"_.

Comment: Which is made obvious by the fact that the error is `trim() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in`

Comment: Sure. So why did you make this answer? What is the use of replacing one error with another?

Comment: I told him what the error is, where to put the `var_dump` and how make his code parse again without errors.. What else is there to add?